# How Deploy EF Code First Apps to Production

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I wrote mvc4 web api application. I have model and controller. Controller include a lot of Get and Post methods.  On a local machine avrything works fine. But now Im trying to sharing my app to production server.
Here is my model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Alllarm.DataContext.Models
{
public class UpdateStatus
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FacebookID { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public bool? FbStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? SmsStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Alarm> Alarms { get; set; }
}

public class Alarm
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int Snoozes { get; set; }
    public bool Repeat { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlarmUpdateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FacebookNotificationStatus> StatusUpdates { get; set; }
    public virtual Sms Sms { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookStatusUpdate
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FacebookUpdateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FacebookPostTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ClientTime { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    public virtual FacebookNotificationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Alarm Alarm { get; set; }
}

public class Sms
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PhoneNumber> SmsNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public enum FacebookNotificationStatus
{
    MessagePosted,
    Cancelled,
    Active,
    Deactivated,
    Overslept
}

public class FBAppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Alarm> Alarms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FacebookStatusUpdate> FacebookStatusUpdates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sms> Smses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

}
```

Please, advice me how run my app on a production server.

Comment: is the question how to deploy asp.net application?
Or how to upgrade the existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

publish the application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.90).aspx

and depending on the DB migration scenario also consider
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx